# What's the difference between 気がする vs 思いをする?

Tags: meaning, nuances

During my flashcard reviews, I once again encountered 思いをする filed under [N1 grammar](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%81%8A%E3%82%82%E3%81%84%E3%82%92%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-omoi-o-suru/). I find it difficult to believe that such a self-explanatory grammar point would be classified as N1 or maybe I was just having some Dunning–Kruger moments taking place.

Anyway, I'd like to ask if 思いをする sends a different "feel" or nuance compared to 気がする.

Comment: it seems 思いをする in your link. 思いがする in your question. Do you want to compare 思いをする and 気がする?

Comment: Without directly commenting on this specific thing... Grammar in the JLPT isn't classified by how easy it is to understand, and some of the N5 grammar items are things that people continue to get wrong when speaking long after they can pass higher levels. Often a reason for something being N1 is just... it never appeared earlier, due to being infrequently used or just having a narrow nuance.

Comment: @kimiTanaka Thanks for your prompt reply. (I guess I was still thinking of this another link I checked while I was writing the question: https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%B0%97%E3%81%8C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) Feel free to add how が and を would change the nuance. But in general, the choice of particle doesn't change the nuance as much as the choice between 思い and 気, right?

Comment: @Leebo That's true I think. Sometimes, the JLPT classification of grammar points can be arbitrary, or like you said, based on frequency and subtlety of nuance.

Comment: 思いがする and 思いをする are different enough. The former is a fairly uncommon construction. Please fix the inconsistency.

Comment: @naruto Thanks for clarifying that. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 7):

At first, I didn't even understand what is 思いをする until I checked your link, because it is never used in isolation. In my mind, it is always a set phrase made of `[description] + 思い` + `する` and I have never broken it down otherwise.

This 思い is explained in [a dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%80%9D%E3%81%84/) as below:

> **７** あることを経験してもたらされる感じ。「胸のすく―」「自分だけいい―をする」

If you play [Rimworld](https://store.steampowered.com/app/294100/RimWorld/), your characters experience various events through a scenario, and get according emotional feedback in the form of "Thoughts" or "Memories". This is what we call ～思い. ～思いをする is that you get/experience a feeling through a certain event. Though not strictly limited to adjectives, some expression that describes your own mental state *must* come before to qualify 思い.

> 嫌な思いをする *have a bad time*

It is almost synonymous to the following expression, which focus more to the event (and only for negative feelings):

> 嫌な[目にあう](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E7%9B%AE%E3%81%AB%E9%81%AD%E3%81%86/) *have a bad experience*

Meanwhile, 気 can be also translated "feeling", but its core meaning is "aura energy". 気がする thus means "catch some omen/indication", which is speculative thought toward a situation yet to happen: "I sense", "it seems", or "I have a hunch". What comes before 気がする is usually the content of expectation rather than emotion.

> 何かがおかしい気がする *feel that something is wrong*

Answer (score 0):

思い is abstract. The word おもう (usually represented with 思 or 想) is [related](http://gogen-allguide.com/o/oboeru.html) to the word おぼえる (both the 覚 and 憶 nuances) and means thought or feeling.
See more here: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%80%9D%E3%81%86-454753

気 implies a more "real" vital energy and intuition.
https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%B0%97-49796

そんな気がした means something like “That was my impression.”

そう思った means “That’s what I thought.”

嫌な気がした means that you that you were vexed or irritated, with the implication that something did not suit your sensibilities.

嫌な思いをした means that something happened to you that you found unpleasant: you had an unpleasant experience, and it wasn't all your fault.

Answer (score 0):

思いをする = to have remembered/experienced

気がする = have a (gut) feeling

One can have a feeling without having experienced it, but it's hard to remember/experience from just a feeling, or so my gut says:

> 経験していないと思いをすることが出来ない気がしますけどｗ

-- Starfox