# The use of causative + には in this sentence

Tags: particle-に, particle-は, causation

[image]

Upon asking the group if they had a bad experience in the village, they deny and she says this.

I understand the first sentence is akin "Starting with the royal family, the village is quite exclusionary.

However I'm stumbled on the meaning of the sentence part. Is she say she made... them feel shame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you seem to understand [肩身が狭い](https://jisho.org/search/%E8%82%A9%E8%BA%AB) is an idiom. Apart from this, the remaining part of the sentence is a simple causative expression. に marks the causee, and は is a topic marker. Also note that [～思いをする](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/78115/5010) is another set phrase.

> そなたらには肩身の狭い思いをさせる。
>
> We will make you have a feeling of "肩身が狭い" (and I feel sorry about it).

Although not explicitly stated, a sense of apology is usually implied in a sentence said by a noble person like this.

One definition of 肩身が狭い is "feeling ashamed", but it's broadly used to describe any situation that makes you feel as if you can't hold your head up high in society. In this case, the visitors (そなたら) might not have done anything shameful in particular, but the exclusive atmosphere of the village makes them feel somewhat *constrained* or *unwelcome*, and that's what 肩身が狭い is referring to.

Comment: The agent would be the causer, the term here is patient

Comment: @Angelos Thanks, removed "agent". I didn't know "patient" can be used here...

Comment: I think you would confuse most native speakers (including me) if you used 'patient' in this context.